# sort dicts in list by dict values

Tags: python, list, sorting

I build up a list like that

```
testList = list()
testList.append('{"_id": "%s", "stuff": "%s", "stuff2": "%s", "stuff3": "%s", "stuff4": "%s"}' % (aList["_id"], aList["stuff"], aCount, anotherList, aList["stuff2"]))
```

now I want to sort testList's dicts by stuff2 (which contains only numbers as values)

I tried:

```
import operator
testList.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2)
```

and

```
testList.sort(key=lambda x: x["stuff2"])
```

and different other solutions I found all over the web :(
My list does not sort or I receive

> TypeError: string indices must be integers sorting

can someone please tell me what's the problem with this one? Do I build up the dicts wrong or is my sort parameter not right?

Thanks in advance,

Codehai

Comment: You know that's just one big string, right? (You put your dict literal in single quotes, so now it's a string.)

Comment: your appending a string not a dictionary....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending string, not a dictionary.
Do this.

```
testList = list()
testList.append({"_id": aList["_id"], "stuff": aList["stuff"], "stuff2": aCount, "stuff3": anotherList, "stuff4": aList["stuff2"]})
```

Comment: probably better than my suggestion to jsonify it :P (+1)

Comment: yea, this is what happens if you copy paste cool stuff like working with placeholders from the internet :-/// thanks for pointing me to my failure!

Answer (score 1):

your appending a string not a dictionary....you can make it a dictionary using the json library

```
testList.sort(key=lambda x: json.loads(x)['stuff2'])
```